# webview is not present in xml layout file but still getting its reference in class file

Tags: android, xml, android-webview

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    deviceId = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
            Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    //Toast.makeText(this, deviceId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//  webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    checkConnection2();
    pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    pd.setMessage("loading");
    pd.show();
```

above is my class file..

and below is my xml layout file-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ycsin.medianewsone.MainActivity" >


</RelativeLayout>
```

Note- i have copied that project from another similar project

the project is working fine with all changes. can please somebody tell me the reason behind this bbug..

Comment: Look at some other XML file. There have to be somewhere an Element with the Id WebView1

Comment: no there is only one xml layout file which i have mentioned above.. is it possible that it is getting reference of webview from another project?? this just like ghost reference for me..